# How to dynamically name a dataset inside an R function using the argument passed in the function?

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a four variable dataframe with 0 rows using a function. I have two requirements here.

1) The name of the newly created dataframe should be the argument passed
2) The name of the second variable in the dataframe should be the argument passed

I tried doing this with the following code:

```
sim<-function(df,df1){

y<-df1

assign(paste(y),data.frame(Var1=numeric(), Var2=numeric(), Var3=numeric(),
                             Var4=numeric()),envir=.GlobalEnv)

colnames(df)[2]<-paste(y)

return(names(df))
}

sim(test,"test")  

colnames(test)
```

I get the following output:

> sim(test,"test")
>
> [1] "Var1" "test" "Var3" "Var4"
>
> colnames(test)
>
> [1] "Var1" "Var2" "Var3" "Var4"

What I don't understand is, when R could understand that 'test' column names are modified and it returns the modified names during the run, dataframe 'test' column names still remain unaltered outside the function. I would appreciate any help to make this work.

Thank you !!

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail on what you're trying to achieve in the big picture? Using a function to create a global environment is OK, but perhaps there's a better way.

Comment: I'm trying to dynamically name the dataset that would be created everytime I use the function. As stated above, I want the global df created to take the name of the argument (in the case above, its 'test') which I'm able to achieve using the above code. But the second condition is to rename the 2nd variable to the name of the argument (in the case above its 'test') which I'm unable to achieve. I'm looking for a solution or a workaround here. Thanks for your response Roman. --Murali

Answer (score 0):

I just figured something. Reason why the function didn't alter the colnames of **'test'** is R can't alter a global dataframe inside a function unless the change is also made global.

Hence the only fix I could think of is by assigning the modifications to the global dataframe **'test'** using the assign function I did nothing but overwrite **'test'**

```
sim<-function(df,df1){

y<-df1    
assign(paste(y),data.frame(Var1=numeric(), Var2=numeric(), Var3=numeric(),
                             Var4=numeric()),envir=.GlobalEnv)

colnames(df)[2]<-paste(y)    
assign(paste(y),df,envir=.GlobalEnv)
}

sim(test,"test")  

colnames(test)
```

The result was this:

> sim(test,"test")
>
> colnames(test)
>
> [1] "Var1" "test" "Var3" "Var4"

I'm pretty sure this is not the efficient way of doing it. I'm curious to know if there could be a simpler solution.